# What is the difference between c++ dynamic binding and java dynamic binding?

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-binding

What is the difference between c++ dynamic binding and java dynamic binding?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ dynamic binding is offered via polymorphism, 
[see Dynamic Binding](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=82) at InformIT.

Here is a stackoverflow discussion on [java dynamic binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding) with nice and simple example.