# Is dynamic overload resolution possible in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

So I have a class of overloaded methods like this:

```
class Foo {
    public void test(Object value) {
        ...
    }

    public void test(String value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to pass a property value of a bean to one of these methods depending on its type, but I don't know the actual property type until the runtime. e.g.

```
public void run(Object bean, String propertyName) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.test(PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, propertyName));
}
```

BTW, `PropertyUtils.getProperty()` is a helper method that returns a value of the specified property on a bean. `PropertyUtils.getProperty()` returns an Object, so that  `test(Object value)` will be always called and the actual property type will be ignored.

I can figure out the propery type in the runtime, even if its value is null. Is there such a thing as dynamic casting in Java? If not, is there a way to have an overloaded method with the correct parameter type called?

Comment: By "dynamic casting", you really mean "dynamic overload resolution", right?

Comment: @Lambert That's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding is what has dynamic binding in Java. Overloading has static binding, and which function is called is determined at compile time, not at runtime. [See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding)

Therefore you can't use overloading for run time selection of methods. Suggest you use one of the other OOP design patterns in java, or at least `instanceof`:

```
public void dispatch(Object o)
{
   if (o instanceof String)
       handleString((String)o);
   else if (o instanceof File)
       handleFile((File)o);
   else
       handleObject(o);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for the Visitor pattern.

Comment: It is if the objects in question can be architected to share a common interface. If not, (e.g. String or Integer or File) then there is some manual testing involved.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded method resolution happens at compile time in Java.  You'll have to do the resolution yourself (a switch, if-then-else ladder or table-lookup), or find a different pattern that can be implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want an answer to this question.  You're interested in setting up a situation where

```
test((String)x)
```

does not do the same thing as

```
test((Object)x)
```

For `x` which are `String`s.  This is a Bad Idea™ and will just lead to lots of confusion.  Use a different method name if you really want different behavior.

Just make `test(Object x)` dispatch to `test(String x)` if `x` is a `String`, then you don't need to worry about which `test` method gets called.