# Which method will be called when overriding a method with different parameters in the following case?

Tags: java, object, equals

Let's say I want to override the method equals() of Object:

```
    public boolean equals(Object o){
      //something
    }

    public boolean equals(SomeClass s){
      //something else
    }
```

SomeClass is obviously also an Object, so which method will be called if I use equals with an Instance of SomeClass as parameter?

Comment: This is overloading and decision to call overloaded method happens at compile time so method which has parameter SomeClass gets called

Comment: Which method will be called? Why not write a test case, it's a matter of 20-30 lines of java code.

Comment: @AmitD he said an instance. We don't know the type for variable that reference the SomeClass object.

Comment: That's not correct. See Costi's answer.

Comment: @user802421 It is compile time decision so if you take the reference to Object method with object gets called.

Comment: A reference and an instance is something different. The author doesn't provide information about the type of the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not overriding, it's overloading. If you do that you'll end up with two `equals` methods: one that will be invoked for (subclasees of) `SomeClass` instances and one for any other objects.

One thing to note is that the method binding will be static: the compiler will decide which one to call based on the declared type of your reference. Therefore, the following will invoke the `equals(Object)`, not `equals(SomeClass)`:

```
Object o = new SomeClass();
o.equals(o);  // invokes SomeClass.equals(Object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to avoid the behavior described in the second paragraph of your post?

Comment: Nope, the only way is to stick to overriding the `equals(Object)` method and inside perform some `instanceof` test.

Answer (score 1):

If you overload the function like in your example, and instantiate the object normally, the equals function with SomeClass as parameter will be called if you provide a SomeClass to the equals function. For any other class, the equals function with an Object as parameter will be called.

If you instantiate your object as a parent class, however, the behaviour is different. This has to do with dynamic binding, which is explained quite well here: [Question about Java overloading & dynamic binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658553/question-about-java-overloading-dynamic-binding)

Note that if you're looking to do something else if the Object is of a SomeClass type, you could also use `instanceof SomeClass` in your standard equals function. (Not trying to start a discussing, but it's an option)

Answer (score 1):

Your `public boolean equals(SomeClass s)` will be called when you invoke it with a parameter `SomeClass` or a sub class of `SomeClass`.

With any other object it will be `public boolean equals(Object o)` that's called.

But when you equals method is being called in other APIs they will call `public boolean equals(Object o)`. Which will lead to erroneous behavior. Java Collection API is an example.

So do not overload the equals method like this.

Comment: `equals(SomeClass s)` will also be called with a parameter that's a subtype of `SomeClass`