# Confused about polymorphism and static binding in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm still quite new to java. So I was reading around polymorphism and static binding while playing around with java. I'm here to clarify if my thinking process is correct.

```java
class A {
    void foo(A a) {
        System.out.println("AAAAAA");
    }

}

class B extends A {
    void foo(B a) {
        System.out.println("BBBBB");
    }

}

class C extends B{
    void foo (A a){
        System.out.println("CCCCCBBBB");
    }

}
```

I created the following object called `c`, and called foo with c as the argument.

```java
C c = new C();
c.foo(c); // the output is BBBBB
```

From this post [Question about Java overloading & dynamic binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658553/question-about-java-overloading-dynamic-binding), I understand that if the argument sent is not found in the class, it will upcast the argument (in this case C) to what can be found in the class (in this case A, since `void foo (A a)`). But if that's the case, shouldn't it print "CCCCCBBBB". through static binding?

Comment: As an aside: Always annotate methods with `@Override` if you intend that method to override one from an ancestor class or an interface. Then the compiler will check for you if that method actually overrides another, emitting an error if it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `C` has 2 overloaded methods with the name `foo`

```
// defined in the class C
void foo (A a){
    System.out.println("CCCCCBBBB");
}

// inherited from the class B
void foo(B a) {
    System.out.println("BBBBB");
}
```

The most specific one will be chosen when we are calling the method `foo` with the parameter of the class `C` - the class `B` is closer by hierarchy than the class `A`, so `foo(B)` is called.