# Feasible way to avoid instanceof in equals method?

Tags: java, equals, instanceof

Many people don't like to use `instanceof`, but I find that in many cases we have few other options when it comes to the `equals` method. Take a look at the class below:

```
class A {   
    int n;
    public A(int n) { this.n = n; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(A o) {
        return n == o.n;
    }   
}
```

I've never seen something like this done, but could it serve as a replacement for having to use `instanceof` to test if an `Object` is an `A`? Or are there other problems that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: I'm curious, why not use `instanceof`? Even the examples that use something like [EqualsBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038204/apache-commons-equals-hashcode-builder) have `instanceof`.

Comment: Didn't get the reason to not using it. I always use it in games.

Comment: @Peter is correct, the overloaded method is not dynamically bound, so this method will rarely get called in typical usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding/322234#322234

Comment: I have nothing against `instanceof`, I was just curious about this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> could it serve as a replacement for having to use instanceof to test if an Object is an A?

No.  This is because the method called is chosen staticly i.e. only `equals(object o)` will be called in most situations.

You can write

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof A && n == ((A) o).n;
}
```

Comment: Yup.  `instanceof` is exactly what you should be using in `equals` methods.

Comment: Seems like you're the one who always answers my questions! So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The collections, Swing components and other classes that use `equals` will still call the `equals(Object o)` version and that will return `false` always.

The example will work when explicitly calling the `equals(A o)` method only.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is overloading not overriding equals. Also don't forget to check for o == null. Alternates to instanceof include getClass().equals(other.getClass()) and using A.isAssignableFrom(other.getClass())