# java polymorphism and inheritance problems

Tags: java

Firstly, I though that java's Polymorphism functions are mapped by it types of parameter instance.

Please, someone help to explain why my function haven't called to `myFunction(EmployeeImpl emp)` sign it instance is `EmployeeImpl`.

```
public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee emp = new EmployeeImpl();
    emp.callMyFunction();
  }
}

abstract class Employee{
  public void callMyFunction(){
    //here is huge amount of code, which all child class has the same
    //excepted this line is called to a different function by it instant types.
    EmployeeFacade.myFunction(this);
  }
}
class EmployeeImpl extends Employee{

}
class EmployeeFacade{
  public static void myFunction(Employee emp){
    //same data to database
    System.out.println("Employee: "+ emp.getClass().getName());
  }
  public static void myFunction(EmployeeImpl emp){
    //same data to database
    System.out.println("EmployeeImpl: "+ emp.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

> Result: Employee: EmployeeImpl

Edited: This is just a sample application with the same structure as my reality application, which has more than 20 children classes that contain the same function called `callMyFunction`, this function has more than 20 lines of code. so it's a very hard work for me to `override` this function with the same code code for all children class. Anyways, What will happen if I need to change my function on the future? Would I change all 20 function with the same code?

Are there anyways easier than this?

Comment: Because you're not overriding `callMyFunction` in the `EmployeeImpl`. When you call an overloaded method, it is determined at compile-time which method will be used. So no matter how this class is inherited at runtime.

Comment: Editing comment because @align explained the behavior you saw a lot better than my comment. I will add this comment though: Look at what would happen if in main() you did EmployeeImpl  emp = new EmployeeImpl(); instead

Comment: So, Must I override my function? what about if myfunction is very hug amount of code. Must I rewrite it again on my subclass?

Comment: @SeSong, I think providing more details on what you are really trying to achieve is good way to get better answers. For example, why all those `myFunction` methods are moved to `EmployeeFacade` class as static methods instead of being virtual methods of the `Employee` class itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first solution (as I suggested in comments) would be to move `myFunction` from the `EmployeeFacade` to `Employee`, `EmployeeImpl` and other subclasses and thus use virtual methods directly. If this for some reasons is not an option, my next solution would be introducing virtual "proxy" function to `Employee` and using it to dispatch call properly:

```
public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee emp = new EmployeeImpl();
    emp.callMyFunction();
  }
}

abstract class Employee
{
    public void callMyFunction()
    {
        //here is huge amount of code, which all child class has the same
        //excepted this line is called to a different function by it instant types.
        callMyFunctionImpl();
    }

    protected void callMyFunctionImpl()
    {
        EmployeeFacade.myFunction(this);
    }
}

class EmployeeImpl extends Employee
{
    @Override
    protected void callMyFunctionImpl()
    {
        EmployeeFacade.myFunction(this);
    }
}

class EmployeeFacade
{
    public static void myFunction(Employee emp)
    {
        //same data to database
        System.out.println("Employee: " + emp.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void myFunction(EmployeeImpl emp)
    {
        //same data to database
        System.out.println("EmployeeImpl: " + emp.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this's useful, work as expected and very small amount of code to rewrite. thanks

Answer (score 8):

Don't exist dynamic binding for overloaded methods ...

Java uses static binding for overloaded methods, and dynamic binding for overridden ones.

[Java dynamic binding and method overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 type of Polymorphism

1)Static polymorphism

2)Dynamic polymorphism

your case is static polymorphism

If you debug your code it's always called

```
public static void myFunction(Employee emp){
  System.out.println("Employee: "+ emp.getClass().getName());
}
```

and every class having getClass() method and it's return the runtime class of the object which has method called.
Here is JDK implementation of Object class

```
 public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

and it's Class class implementation

```
    public String getName() {
    String name = this.name;
    if (name == null)
        this.name = name = getName0();
    return name;
}
```

Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String.

Comment: Are there anyways to make it dynamic, because I have more than 20 children classes and hug amount of code inside `callMyFunction`. Anyways facade function are do different jobs.