# Call toString() when convert String to Object

Tags: java

Here is my example code:

```
String str = "hello";
Object obj = (Object)str;
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

I found the source code of Object, and the toString() method is:

```
public String toString() {   
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

I thought the result of the example shound be the address of this Object, like [B@15db9742 , after I convert str to Object , but it still print hello. Why? Shoundn't obj use the method of Object? Can Anyone explain the principle of it to me?

Comment: Welcome to [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). :-) *(There must be a dupetarget for this.)*

Comment: *Method Overriding* - You are changing only the reference type, the actual object is *still a String* and the `toString` of `String` returns the actual string

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding

Comment: ...and yet I'm not finding a really good one. But that just has to be me running out of time to search.

Comment: You are not *converting* a `String` to an `Object` - you are *casting* (and in this case, the cast isn't even necessary, you could just do `Object obj = str;` without casting). Casting does not change (i.e. convert) an object.

Answer (score 5):

This is [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) (specifically, *runtime polymorphism*). It doesn't matter what the type of your reference to the object is (`Object` or `String`), as long as that type has `toString` (so your code compiles), the `toString` that will be used is the one the object itself actually has, not necessarily the one provided by the type of your reference. In this case, the object is a `String` no matter what the type of your reference to it is, so `String#toString` is used.

Answer (score 2):

Because the underlying object is a String object and the String class has overridden the `toString()` method in it.

Though you have the type Object on left hand, the methods from implemented Class gets execute and the overall phenomenon called as Polymorphism. You are Just changing the Form of String to Object.

When you do

```
Object obj = (Object)str;
```

That doesn't change String to Object class. You are just changing the type of the Object not the actual behaviour of it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual method invocation implies the method override will be executed given the actual implementation, as opposed to the implementation in the reference type.

In other words, your `String` instance will still invoke overrides of `Object`'s methods implemented in `String`, even if cast as `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Object **obj** is the result of an (unnecessary) cast, but is still a String....
the String class has an implemented overide of **toString** method:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

verify that obj is a String by doing:

```
System.out.println(str.getClass());
System.out.println(obj.getClass());
```

you will get

> class java.lang.String
>
> class java.lang.String